# Twitter like svg text counter with css and jquery- https://jsfiddle.net/moss24/LnoL2xdu/

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a twitter like text counter that increments a green color width until its 75% and then append a yellow color until it 98% and a red color if the input value is >= 400 add a class called the highlight. Same way, when a user hit the backspace key/delete a text in any way to decrements the color width.
A link has been attached above.

I would very much appreciate your support.

Comment: What do you have done so far?

Comment: check out the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/moss24/LnoL2xdu/

Answer (score 0):

Too much javascript, it can be done much simpler using just a small piece of code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.textCounter = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            maxText: 400,
            textWarning: 75
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).on('keyup', function() {
                var textLength = $(this).val().length;
                var progressbar = $('#commentTxtCounter > span');
                var progressbarLength = (textLength*100)/settings.maxText;
                if (progressbarLength > 100) {
                    progressbarLength = 100;
                }
                progressbar.css('width', progressbarLength + '%');
                if (textLength == 0 || textLength >= settings.maxText) {
                    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                if (textLength >= settings.maxText) {
                    progressbar.attr('class', 'text-over');
                } else if (textLength >= settings.textWarning) {
                    progressbar.attr('class', 'text-warn');
                } else {
                    progressbar.attr('class', 'text-safe');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
$('.text-control').textCounter();
```

with a little less html:

```
<textarea class="text-control " rows="1" data-min-rows="1" placeholder="comment..."></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
<div class="counter-cont">
    <div class="counter-sub" id="commentTxtCounter">
        <span class="text-safe"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job, but i would like it if the progressbar are appended after each one has reach it max length instead of possessing the entire container

Comment: Can you draw it? I have no clear idea how you want it to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. the final path is that when the textLength >= settings.maxText then the over text value should be highlighted with a light-red color to show that the value has exceeded it max input

Comment: background-color i mean

Comment: hmm... interesting challenge, I will try to achieve this :)

Comment: Good, I'm trying too.

Comment: I spend a couple of hours on this and finally I found that to achieve this you need to make some tricky things described here: https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/